# How to open protected .eslock file on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, archiving

How to open .eslock file on WIndows 7 that has inside zip archive given we know the ES lock encryption password?

Comment: Easy, enter the password. or...https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-decrypt-an-encrypted-ES-explorer-file-without-the-password

Comment: 7zip cannot open the file

Answer (score 1):

install any emulation software like blue stacks or mobogenie or youwave and try es file lock decryptor pro apk